# Docker mssql container exits immediately when Docker starts, but not when started manually

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a MSSQL 2017 Docker container created using Docker Compose with this file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mssql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "*****"
    ports:
      - "2017:1433"
    container_name: test-mssql
```

Whenever Docker Desktop for Windows starts, the container starts and then immediately exits. The logs only contain 2 lines:

> 2019-01-18 16:56:43.02 spid6s      Always On: The availability replica manager is going offline because SQL Server is shutting down. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2019-01-18 16:56:43.05 spid6s      SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

But if I start the container manually by running `docker start test-mssql` the container starts and stays running like I expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

This issue related mssql password policy not match, Now try with password like :

- Must be at least 8 characters long
- Must contain at least 1 numeric character,
- 1 lowercase character,
- 1 uppercase character, and 1 special (nonalphanumeric) character.

Then try to run **docker-compose up -d mssql-server**

Comment: Mayur is correct. I tried simplifying the pw compared to the usage guide I’d seen. That cost me some time debugging wth was going on